# How to get data from my MySQL database into Zoho Books.?

Tags: mysql, database, zoho

I have a database in MySQL and I am using Zoho Books for keeping my accounts.

1. I want to update my Zoho Books with the pre-existing revenues data from the database. How to do this?
2. I want to automate this task, that everytime a change is made into the database, Zoho Books extracts the data from it. If not automate, atleast I want to make this process easy - to reflect all the revenues in the database as my inflows in Zoho Books. How to do this?

I haven't found any answers on StackOverflow regarding this topic, please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Zoho Books extracts the data from it

It is very unlikely that "Zoho would query YOUR database" (I mean why would they provide this service where they would have access to YOUR database?).

If I'm getting what you are saying then:

You should "watch" for any, for example changes in your revenues for the day (in your database) and make an api call (a POST http method call, to "write" your changes by first fetching it from your database by querying it) to your particular Zoho account (this is where you need to explore their api well), and your job would be done.

Two questions here now:

1. Can you "watch" for the changes of data in your database? (does MYSQL support that in any way?)
2. Find out the http post method apis to do the same.

Let me know if I didn't understand something correctly.

Answer (score 3):

To have your revenue figures reflect in Zoho Books, you can opt to choose one of the two options below :

1. Zoho Books supports CSV Import. If you can get your data extracted from your database as a CSV file, you can import it in Zoho Books. This [help link](https://www.zoho.com/books/help/import-export/import.html) depicts more about this.
2. Zoho Books provides REST APIs through which you can add your data and work with it, if you can somehow retrieve the same from your DB and hit out api calls to Zoho Books. Here's the [API documentation](https://www.zoho.com/books/api/v3/) that would guide you through the same.

P.S. While the former requires a manual work, the latter can be automated if you have a service that could watch out the changes in your DB and hit corresponding API calls to Zoho Books.

You can also checkout Zoho Creator, that can be used as an intermediate to build an application, that would fetch data from your service and sync with Zoho Books.

Btw, could you post more details on your requirement and use case here?